# Error using anonymous function for system of ODE using ode45 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a system of `n` coupled ODE in MATLAB. The code:

```
clear all
n = 21;
dx = 1./(n-1);
x = [0:dx:1];
u0 = sin(0.5*n*pi*x);
f1 = @(t,u) [0, u(1:n-2)-2*u(2:n-1)-u(3:n), 2*(u(n-1)-u(n))]'/dx^2;
% f1 = @(t,u) [0; u(1:n-2)'-2*u(2:n-1)'-u(3:n)'; 2*(u(n-1)-u(n))]/dx^2;
[t,U] = ode45(f1, [0,2.5], u0');
```

gives the error:

```
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
Error in t1>@(t,u)[0,u(1:n-2)-2*u(2:n-1)-u(3:n),2*(u(n-1)-u(n))]'/dx^2
```

I get errors from both forms (one commented out) of the anonymous function when `u` is a column vector, as it is when the function is called through `ode45`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `u` passed to `f1` by `ode45` is a column vector.  The concatenation must reflect this:

```
f1 = @(t,u) [0 ; u(1:n-2)-2*u(2:n-1)-u(3:n) ; 2*(u(n-1)-u(n))]/dx^2;
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem.